# Как сконвертировать в sRGB картинку с профилем ICC и удалить сам профиль?

Tags: python, pillow

Делаю веб-сайт на питоне, в админке которого можно загружать картинки на сайт. Обнаружилось, что если загружать JPEG-фотки с хорошего фотоаппарата, то на сайте фотки отображаются менее насыщенными, чем они отображаются во всяких фотошопах, хотя никакой их обработки никем не производилось.

Выяснилось, что JPEG-фотки имеют профиль ICC, отличающийся от стандартного sRGB (если конкретно, ProPhoto RGB), а браузеры этот профиль использовать не умеют и отображают цвета как попало.

Отсюда задача: c помощью Pillow (на сайте используется он) перевести картинку в обычный sRGB и убрать профиль ICC из неё, чтоб не мешался.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За работу с цветовыми профилями в Pillow отвечает модуль `PIL.ImageCms` (использует в своей основе библиотеку Little CMS), и его метод `profileToProfile` позволяет конвертировать картинки из одного профиля в другой — вот в sRGB и сконвертируем.

У меня получилась такая функция, которая умеет обрабатывать как минимум JPEG и PNG с цветовыми режимами RGB, CMYK и P (протестировано на Pillow 9.4):

```py
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageCms

def remove_icc(image: Image.Image) -> Image.Image:
    """
    Убирает у картинки ICC-профиль и ставит обычный sRGB, который не имеет
    проблем с отображением на разных устройствах. Возвращает копию картинки
    с убранным профилем.
    """

    icc_bytes = image.info.get("icc_profile") or b""
    if not icc_bytes:
        # Если ICC-профиля нет, то просто возвращаем копию картинки
        return image.copy()

    # Читаем ICC-профиль из картинки
    orig_icc = ImageCms.getOpenProfile(BytesIO(icc_bytes)).profile
    # Получаем обычный профиль sRGB, в который будем конвертировать
    srgb_icc = ImageCms.createProfile("sRGB")

    # Помогаем Pillow выполнить преобразование цветовых режимов там, где он сам
    # не справляется (из-за необходимости этого преобразования использовать
    # inPlace=True в общем случае не получится)
    mode = image.mode
    tmp_image = None
    if mode == "CMYK":
        mode = "RGB"
    elif mode == "P":
        mode = "RGBA"
        tmp_image = image.convert("RGBA")

    # Создаём сконвертированную копию картинки
    try:
        result = ImageCms.profileToProfile(
            tmp_image or image, orig_icc, srgb_icc, outputMode=mode
        )
    finally:
        if tmp_image is not None:
            tmp_image.close()

    # Удаляем информацию о профиле sRGB, чтобы всякие гимпы
    # не предлагали сконвертировать sRGB в sRGB
    result.info.pop("icc_profile")

    # Имейте в виду, что profileToProfile при создании копии картинки
    # не переносит мета-информацию вроде EXIF. Если она вам нужна, придётся
    # позаботиться о её копировании самостоятельно
    if image.info.get("exif"):
        result.info["exif"] = image.info["exif"]

    return result
```

Метод `profileToProfile` также имеет другие аргументы, которые могут быть вам интересны; подробнее см. в [документации Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageCms.html).